# How to write this docker command with kubectl

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I'd like to use kubectl to run this docker image :

```
docker run --rm -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD=monpassword docker.io/inseefrlab/utilitr:latest
```

I'm looking for the equivalent kubectl command.

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: You have a docker cmd that (pulls an imagine if it's not on local) starts a container and exposes port 8787, where kubectl allows you to run commands against Kubernetes clusters. What do you want more exactly ? it's not clear

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to find a way to start a container going through kubernetes with kubectl. If it's not possible, too bad. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/docker-cli-to-kubectl/

Comment: Typically you'd write a Kubernetes YAML file describing a Deployment and a corresponding Service, commit it to source control, and submit it to the cluster using `kubectl apply -f`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not that it is not possible, just not the best way to run via an equivalent kubectl command as that would mean running kubectl interactively. But, if that's what you ask, you can use these:

```
kubectl run utilitr --image=inseefrlab/utilitr:latest
```

&

```
kubectl port-forward utilitr 8787:8787
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pod first in the remote cluster and then use port-forward to connect to the pod via `localhost:8787`

```
kubectl run <podname> --image=inseefrlab/utilitr:latest --env="PASSWORD=monpassword"
kubectl port-forward <podname> 8787:8787
```